# Wrap Text in android?

Tags: android

I want to achieve wrap text in android. I am using following attributes but still couldnt be able to achieve

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:text="@string/hello" />         // @String/hello <string name="hello">Hello,How are you world whatsup</string>
```

Anyone please help ?

Comment: @Dr.nik: What else do you want? The given description and code is more enough to understand the problem..!

Comment: what do you mean by wrap ? can you post screenshots of what you are getting and which one you require ?

Comment: @YugandharBabu  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171538/how-to-achieve-wrap-text-on-canvas-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textview01"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:ellipsize="none"
  android:scrollHorizontally="false"
  android:text="@string/hello" />
```

Comment: Not working I tried. I want to add that I am drawing this text view on canvas is it going to affect it by any chance ?

Comment: check this out actually what I want to achieve is this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171538/how-to-achieve-wrap-text-on-canvas-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I tried ur code by replacing  @string/hello = "Hello,How are you world whatsup. Hello,How are you world whatsup" and it worked fine.

may be other views in ur layout are affecting your TextView

### try adding "android:layout_weight="1""

Comment: I am drawing this text on Canvas.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171538/how-to-achieve-wrap-text-on-canvas-in-android

Comment: I added layout_weight also but could not achieve it still the same