# How to achieve Wrap Text on Canvas in Android

Tags: android

Hello I am trying to achieve wrap text in textview which is being drawn via canvas
Here is the code

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

Here is the string.xml

```
<resources>

<string name="hello">Hello,How are you world whatsup Hello,How are you world whatsup Hello,How are you world whatsup Hello,How are you world whatsup </string>
<string name="app_name">GradientEffect</string>
```

and here is the line where I am drawing it on the canvas and applying shader tweak for gradient

```
String input=secondTextView.getText().toString();
    p.setShader(textShader);
    p.setTextSize(50);
    canvas.drawText(input, 100, 400, p);
```

But I am not able to achieve it ?